# Int Value into text Field

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

In JavaFX, I have a TextField Called "randomIntegerField" I need to auto populate this textfield JavaFX with an integer value returned by a method when i clik on a button.

Here is the method which return the int Value

```
private int randomNum(){
     Random random = new Random();
     int integerIntered = Integer.parseInt(numberField.getText()); 
     return   random.nextInt(integerIntered - 0 + 1) + 0; 
}
```

Here is the Button

```
 bntGo.setText("Go");
    
    bntGo.setOnAction(e -> {
       randomIntegerField = String.valueOf(randomNum()); // The error i get is String can not converted into TextField. 
    });
```

Help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [text property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#textProperty) of `randomIntegerField` (which I assume is a `TextField`), for example...

```java
bntGo.setOnAction(e -> {
       randomIntegerField.setText(String.valueOf(randomNum())); 
});
```